# Safely open suspicious email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, office365

I just received a suspicious email (judging by the sender and subject line). It is probably a phishing attempt, but I'd like to look at it to verify.

However, I also want to ensure it won't execute any embedded Javascript, pull any images from the web, give any indication to the sender that it has been opened in any way. I simply want to look at the body of the email.

Is this possible?

My Outlook Standard 2010 (Version 14.0.7162.5000 32-bit) is Office-365 enabled.

Comment: Disconnect your internet connection before opening it.

Comment: Which will do absolutely nothing for in-message scripts, which can in themselves cause significant harm.  The best protection, IMO, is to avoid Outlook entirely.

Comment: can you disable java from control panel ? else can you open in web browser after disabling java/java-script, or can you save the email as plain text and check it that way ?

Comment: The simplest method would be to open the email in a text only format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move it to "Junk E-Mail" folder before opening. After that you can browse it safely: Outlook disables all active functionality (like links/external images/scripts/...) for junk messages.

Comment: Oh nice. I did this and it even told me "Links and other functionality have been disabled in this message". Sweet!

Comment: And, of course, Microsoft *never* tells users anything that isn't absolutely true.  "No one could ever possibly need more than 640k of RAM." -- Bill Gates.  I wouldn't believe Outlook telling me that as a protection from a known suspicious messsage's inclusions.  No, I don't have an answer for you, I'm just telling you I don't completely trust this one.

Comment: @ZeissIkon That's a pretty strawman argument. The actual 'quote' is "640K ought to be enough for anybody", not near as strong as "could ever possibly". Of course it's possible there's bugs or something they forgot, but this is the intended functionality and honestly, as frustrating as Microsoft products can be sometimes, I can't think of a single software product they put out that a competitor does better (except their OS for phones, they should stay away from phones...). YMMV

Comment: @corsiKa I WINCEd at your comment and was going to post a list, but decided not to start.

Comment: @mpez0 Probably a good idea since I specifically called out their mobile OS... I suppose you could say "technically, CE isn't Phone" in which case I'd invoke xkcd 1475.

Comment: @corsiKa I realized I was at the edge of flamewar territory, but couldn't resist the first pun. Say, WINCE is to Phone as Multiplan is to Excel. Oh wait, I mentioned Multiplan... sorry.

Comment: Let's not talk about... that thing we're not going to talk about...